# Wrong EntitlementType receiving in token Excel Addin ms-office

Tags: ms-office, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins

I have developed [Excel Web Add-in](https://store.office.com/en-us/app.aspx?assetid=WA104380662&sourcecorrid=a242b13a-9bd5-4961-aedb-028683f6cdec&searchapppos=0&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&appredirect=false) and submitted is successfully to the store.
Basically this is charting application which draw charts by reading data from sheet.

Initially we launched it as free add-in. Later-on we changed its type to Monthly Subscription and 30 Days trial as well for users to evaluate it.

Now how do we license the add-in.

1. We give full access of add-in to the user in trial period. We just only show trial mark on all charts in trial Period.
2. We check if "EntitlementType" in "et" query string variable  is "Trial" the we show trial, if "Paid" then we remove the trial mark from add-in that user has purchased full version.

**Here comes the problem**

To test licensing process we purchased this app from two different accounts.

User 1: This user first downloaded the add-in as a trial. Then purchased it from store. We were surprised to know that "EntitlementType" was still coming "Trial". We removed the cache refresh the system but still entitlement type's value is coming "Trial", and user were getting message "You are trying out this app.Buy it to get full version"; however user has purchased.

**Token**

```
 <r v="1"><t aid="WA104380662" pid="21a3b99d-0cbe-4b35-836a-73c159c7c1af" cid="F886A2CB4734570D" ts="1" et="Trial" ad="2017-01-12T16:01:32Z" ed="2017-03-13T16:01:32Z" sd="2017-01-12" te="2017-03-17T16:01:32Z" ss="0" /><d>ooji86KTu08hZ8QR2b3UcS9pps0WtAzWq+bAxvnCnZY=</d></r>
```

User 2: This user used this add-in when it was free. Now after we updated the add-in to monthly subscription, this user decided to purchase the add-in. User purchased it successfully, "EntitlementType" of this users was "Free" before purchasing it and still "Free" after purchasing it.

We are unable to track in these above two scenario's that user has purchased the add-in, because we track it using "EntitlementType" property and in above cases its value is not "Paid", we have coded to remove trial mark only if "EntitlementType"=="Paid"

**Token**

```
<r v="1"><t aid="WA104380662" pid="21a3b99d-0cbe-4b35-836a-73c159c7c1af" cid="38F8FF1D6663619F" ts="0" sl="true" et="Free" ad="2017-01-23T10:10:52Z" sd="2017-01-23" te="2018-01-23T10:10:52Z" ss="0" /><d>/oYKY1GqV0eGQQ2/C9XF1CSqdh43ZTQSWgerwrEsEWo=</d></r>
```

1. [We used the following article and code according to our requirement.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/officeapps/2012/11/01/creating-and-verifying-licensing-in-a-paid-app-for-office/)

In need help in resolving this issue.

Comment: You might consider adding office-js tag and removing excel tag

Comment: Which host are you experiencing this issue on? (Excel for Windows, Excel Online or Excel Mac)?

Comment: excel for windows

Comment: @HumbertoLezama please help, i am stuck on it from few weeks.

Comment: @HumbertoLezama any thought on question?

Comment: I pinged folks from our store team to take a look